# How do we remove duplicate from array. Remove the first object at Top level javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

How can I remove the duplicate from the root. Basically I want to look at the full array at the UUID property. If a UUID from the root of the array is found anywhere else in the array I want to remove the object from the root.

Example: "UUID": "9E741BEC-7BC1-49C0-8214-AB5A65762CB7" is found to the top level of the tree. Its also found in one of the Children. so I want to remove the on that is at the top level

```
{
  "UUID": "9E741BEC-7BC1-49C0-8214-AB5A65762CB7",
  "Visible": false,
  "WasVisibleTransient": false,
  "WhichCorners": 15,
  "Width": 796.5216064453125,
  "Width2": 796.5216064453125,
  "Width3": 796.5216064453125,
  "title": "Frances Stowe Great lesson "
  },
  {
    "UUID": "9E741BEC-7BC",
    "Visible": false,
    "WasVisibleTransient": false,
    "WhichCorners": 15,
    "Width": 796.5216064453125,
    "Width2": 796.5216064453125,
    "Width3": 796.5216064453125,
    "title": "Nice to know, 
    "Children": [{
      "UUID": "9E741BEC-7BC1-49C0-8214-AB5A65762CB7",
      "Visible": false,
      "WasVisibleTransient": false,
      "WhichCorners": 15,
      "Width": 796.5216064453125,
      "Width2": 796.5216064453125,
      "Width3": 796.5216064453125,
      "title": "Frances Stowe Great lesson ",
      "Children": [{
        "UUID": "9E741",
        "Visible": false,
        "WasVisibleTransient": false,
        "WhichCorners": 15,
        "Width": 796.5216064453125,
        "Width2": 796.5216064453125,
        "Width3": 796.5216064453125,
        "title": "Frances Stowe Great lesson "
      }],
    }],
  },
  {
    "UUID": "9E741BEC-7BC",
    "Visible": false,
    "WasVisibleTransient": false,
    "WhichCorners": 15,
    "Width": 796.5216064453125,
    "Width2": 796.5216064453125,
    "Width3": 796.5216064453125,
    "title": "Nice to know
  },
},
```

The output I would like is below

```
{
      "UUID": "9E741BEC-7BC",
      "Visible": false,
      "WasVisibleTransient": false,
      "WhichCorners": 15,
      "Width": 796.5216064453125,
      "Width2": 796.5216064453125,
      "Width3": 796.5216064453125,
      "title": "Nice to know, 
      "Children": [{
        "UUID": "9E741BEC-7BC1-49C0-8214-AB5A65762CB7",
        "Visible": false,
        "WasVisibleTransient": false,
        "WhichCorners": 15,
        "Width": 796.5216064453125,
        "Width2": 796.5216064453125,
        "Width3": 796.5216064453125,
        "title": "Frances Stowe Great lesson ",
        "Children": [{
          "UUID": "9E741",
          "Visible": false,
          "WasVisibleTransient": false,
          "WhichCorners": 15,
          "Width": 796.5216064453125,
          "Width2": 796.5216064453125,
          "Width3": 796.5216064453125,
          "title": "Frances Stowe Great lesson "
        }],
      }],
    },
    {
      "UUID": "9E741BEC-7BC",
      "Visible": false,
      "WasVisibleTransient": false,
      "WhichCorners": 15,
      "Width": 796.5216064453125,
      "Width2": 796.5216064453125,
      "Width3": 796.5216064453125,
      "title": "Nice to know
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function removeRootUUID(baseArray, currArray) {
    const delInRoot = (uuidRef) => {
        baseArray.forEach( (obj, i) => {
            if (obj.UUID === uuidRef) {
                baseArray.splice(i, 1);
            }
        });
    }
    for (const obj of currArray) {
        if (obj.Children) {
            obj.Children.forEach( cObj => {
                delInRoot(cObj.UUID);
            })
            removeRootUUID(baseArray, obj.Children);
        }
    };
}

// arr is your initial array here
removeRootUUID(arr, arr);
console.log(arr);
```

I'm sure it could be better, but it works with your example

Comment: so would it be: 
removeRootUUID(response.data.items, response.data.items);
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.items));

Comment: @Jerryseigle Yes I guess

Comment: Okay yes I tried this but just printed the original array

Comment: @Jerryseigle On my side the first object gets removed; Is you response object well of the following form: `{ data: { items: [ {}, {}, ... ] } }`?

Comment: The data structure changes however there is always a UUID and Children property in each object